# Force Chrome to follow URL and not search

Tags: google-chrome

I use JIRA and when I want to navigate to a new task, I just change the number in the URL to go there, e.g.

```
http://jira.mycompany.internal/jira/browse/FOO-1
```

is edited to:

```
http://jira.mycompany.internal/jira/browse/FOO-2
```

and away I go.

However, recently (today) Chrome has decided to search instead of following the URL. This is extremely annoying, but there is a work around.

If I wait for a moment, Chrome presents options to search or follow the URL, so I can edit the URL, wait, press down arrow to select the URL, then press enter.

However, that is a pain and there may be more than one URL match (even though I want the exact one I typed). This is a huge pain, and enough to make me quit Chrome if it can't be fixed.

PS. I tried to disable searching from the address bar and found some useful tips on the web (e.g. [*Google Chrome - Disable searches from the address bar*](http://ccm.net/faq/39472-google-chrome-disable-searches-from-the-address-bar)), but there is no flag for it now (I'm using v49.0.2623.112).

Can anyone tell me how to fix this so that when I type a URL, Chrome follows the URL by default and doesn't do a search?

#### Edit

Per Dave Ross' answer, this is a won't fix bug in Chrome. In addition to the above work around, there is:

1. change URL, press `<tab>` to move to the second item in the search list before it's displayed, then `<enter>`
2. end the URL with a trailing slash '/'

I think the second option is the best, thought both are annoying.

#### Edit 2018-09-07

This appears fixed in Chrome 68 (no need for trailing slash, etc.), it may have been fixed earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30636) that the developers won't fix. You'll probably be ok switching to one of the internal TLDs defined by RFC2606:

- .test
- .example
- .invalid
- .localhost
- .local
- .lan
- .priv
- .localdomain

We use .local where I work.

Comment: I am now experiencing this issue using `.invalid`. The `.local` has the quirk, that iOS, when set to connect through a proxy, will not let the proxy resolve it. This (I believe) makes it impossible to point an iOS device on something running on your dev-box under `.local` TLD.

Comment: We use .lan at my workplace and Chrome 109 insists on searching if I don't type http:// first.

Answer (score 7):

To disable search engine:

1. Launch Chrome
2. Click on the three point button
3. Settings
4. On *Search engine*, click on the arrow on *Manage search engines*
5. Click on *Add*
6. On *Search engine*, type anything (URL)
7. On *Keyword*, type anything (URL)
8. On *URL*, type `%s`
9. Click on *Done*
10. Click on the three point button on the new line -> Make Default

PS: Wording may be wrong. My browser is not in English. The idea is to add a search engine that *is* the URL

Answer (score 4):

Two things needed.

You ***Must*** Disable the network detect settings in google chrome.

[chrome://settings](http://chrome://settings)

-> Advanced Settings ;

**disable** Prediction service to complete
**disable** Web service to resolve navigation errors.

Then, the above HTTP:// will resolve (regardless of the domain, the "correct" answer is nonsense

---

You can also add simple slashes behind D.TLD routes, regardless of name

Example:

`site.n` <-- fails

`site.n/` <--- works

Comment: the / at the end does the trick to force browser to threat input as a url (at least in edge)